# What is another way to phrase “continuing in character” in the same context as stated in the body of this post?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> These Interrogatories are continuing in character so as to require you to file supplementary answers if you obtain further or different information before trial.

I believe the the first five words of the excerpt above could be stated more plainly.

Is “continuing in character” even grammatically correct?

How would one rephrase this without changing it dramatically?

Comment: You mean they acted the same way they usually do, or something slightly different (according to their personality or inner feelings rather than external rules or conventions)? Also, Interrogatories isn’t a usual English word and sounds French or something.

Comment: Some context in [Federal Rules of Civil Procedure](https://www.law.cornell.edu/rules/frcp/rule_33)

Comment: Your question is about "the first five words" = **These Interrogatories are continuing in** yet you include **character**. What exactly do you mean?

Comment: Where does the example come from, please?

Answer (score 1):

The sentence says that if, after answering questions in the interrogatories, new information is obtained, you are required to inform the other party.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrogatories):

> In law, **interrogatories** [...] are a formal set of written questions propounded by one litigant and required to be answered by an adversary [...]

In law, "*[continuing](https://thelawdictionary.org/continuing/)*" means

> Enduring; not terminated by a single act or fact

A simpler rephrasing could then be:

"These Interrogatories are not finished after the initial response and you are required to file supplementary answers if you obtain further or different information before trial."

Comment: I don't think the OP understands how "in character" is being used, it would be helpful if you explained that in the answer.